# Can I manage a has_one relationship with Gridfield (or similar) in Silverstripe?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We have an object with a `has_one` relationship with a secondary object in a Silverstripe project. The secondary object has multiple `has_one` fields

```
class IceCream extends DataObject
{

  private static $has_one = [
    'Cone' => 'Cone'
  ]
}

class Cone extends DataObject
{
  private static $has_one = [
    'Size' => 'Size',
    'Pattern' => 'Pattern'
  ]

}
```

We want to be able to edit the secondary object `Cone` from the `IceCream` object in the CMS. Both creating new `Cone` records or linking existing `Cone` records.

If `Cone` was in a `many_many` relationship we could use `Gridfield` with the [symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions](https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions) module. And use the `GridFieldAddExistingSearchButton` & `GridFieldAddNewInlineButton` extensions.

Is there anyway to use this sort of behaviour for a `has_one` relationship?

I've investigated using the [stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit](https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit) module but it only appears to enable inline editing of `has_one` fields (in this example `Size` & `Pattern`) & doesn't appear to allow the user to link existing `Cone` records.

How can we create a field in the CMS that allows the user to link or create `has_one` records - preferably inline or as a modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of modules you can use to do this.

Our preference is https://github.com/satrun77/silverstripe-hasoneselector, some other community members prefer to use https://github.com/silvershop/silverstripe-hasonefield, which is also a dependency of quite widely used https://github.com/gorriecoe/silverstripe-linkfield. Might be a better option in terms of support.